# Problems Showing ListView on Json Retrofit Screen

Tags: android, json, android-studio, retrofit2

I have the following `Json` information and I want to take it out for a `Listview`:

```java
{"result":[[[12,"01",1,"Fallo de corriente",0,1],
            [12,"01",2,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo (activaci\u00F3n)",0,0],
            [12,"01",3,"Nivel m\u00E1ximo(desactivaci\u00F3n)",0,1]]]
}
```

The fact is that the application gives me an error and I don't tip it, I have it mounted like this:

I have the `POST` class that is well as follows:

```java
package com.example.lista.Interface;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.lang.Integer;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Post {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<List<List<Integer>>> result = null;

    public List<List<List<Integer>>> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<List<List<Integer>>> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    }
```

The PostService interface:

```java
package com.example.lista.Interface;

    import java.util.List;
    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.http.GET; 
    import retrofit2.http.Header;

    public interface PostService {

    String API_ROUTE = " obtenerListaAlarmasSMS";

    @GET(API_ROUTE)
    Call<Post> getPost(@Header("Authorization") String credencialesEnBase64);

    }
```

And I have the Main as follows

```java
package com.example.lista.Interface;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.example.lista.R; 

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.lang.String;


    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Callback;
    import retrofit2.Response;
    import retrofit2.Retrofit;
    import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

    import static retrofit2.Response.error;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView list;
    List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> titles  = new 
    ArrayList<List<List<List<Integer>>>>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    String usuario = new String("");
    String clave = new String("");
    String error = new String("Algo ha fallado");

    String credenciales =  usuario + ":" + clave ;;
    String credencialesEnBase64 = "Basic " + 
    Base64.encodeToString(credenciales.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
        list = findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        getPosts();
    }

    private void getPosts() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()              
              .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.249:9096/datasnap/rest/TMetodosREST/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
        Call<Post> call = postService.getPost(credencialesEnBase64);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

                    for (Post post : response.body()) {
                       titles.add(post.getResult());
                   }

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
     }
     }
```

The problem comes in the OnResponse for which it tells me:

> error: for-each not applicable to expression type
>   required: array or java.lang.Iterable
>   found:    Post

I don't know if it's because of the format of the POJO that creates me or what happens to it.

What I want is to get the information in the `ListView`

Comment: Please read the Error. It says your response providing Post. and forEach looking for Array.

Comment: First you need to save it in Post Class then use for loop for getting result list item.

Comment: @ChandraShekharKaushik
I really admit that I don't know how to do it, what do I have to keep, how do I have to do it, won't it be the fault of the json format?
I am a bit lost.

Comment: If your debugger is going inside the onResponse then there is no issue with your JSON Format.  Use it like this :- Post post  = (Post) response.body();   then you can access result from post object.

Comment: @ChandraShekharKaushik  put that line in my onResponse

Post post = (Post) response.body ();

And just below I try to add the result of getResult to the listView called "titles" as follows:

titles.add (post.getResult ());

But it tells me that invoking this method causes a "NullPointerException"

And it doesn't get me anything on the listWiew.

Comment: try debugging the value of post object, what it contains? Does it have the value that coming from the API as a result.

Comment: @ChandraShekharKaushik Something clearly happens with the json giving me the following error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For the input string: "Fallo de Corriente"

And if I debug, I get to the method that gives the error:
 
    public Number read (JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek () == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull ();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return in.nextInt ();
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException (e);
      }
Something happens.

Comment: Buddy, according to your above question are you able to get response in post object or not 
:

Comment: @ChandraShekharKaushik Yes, I have an answer but it gives me Null due to an error since my Json has numbers and strings and my arrayList is an integer ...

How can I manage this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As per your output

[12,"01",1,"Fallo de corriente",0,1]
```

It contains both Integer & String. And you are expecting Integer

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> result
```

that's why it throws `NumberFormatException`

Convert all Integer into String 
`["12","01","1","Fallo de corriente","0","1"]`

and expect result in `String` like this

```
List<List<List<String>>> result
```

Comment: How can I solve that?
Having strings and int how do I manage that?

Comment: Use this `List<List<List<Object>>> result`. It will solve the error.
If not, Please post what you got in response

Comment: I get an error telling me this: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fallo de corriente"

Comment: Please post what you got in api response

Comment: Use [okHttp-logging-interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to print retrofit API log in logcat

Comment: I apologize, it worked as you told me with:
List <List <List <Object> >>

It is perfect!